# (Arcpy) read values from a txt file and convert the data into a shapefile

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, shapefile, coordinate-system

I´m a beginner at python programming and wanted to start with a litte and hopefully simple project. I tried to read float values out of a textfile and write them into a shapefile.

The program is working fine until the writing in the shapefile. Following error occurs:

```
TypeError: value #0 - unsupported type: list
TypeError: sequence size must match size of the row
```

I tried different styles (last lines in the code) but i could´t work it out.
So my question is: What is my error and what could i do to solve this Problem?

Example of the Textfile ("test.txt"):

```
2500000.00 5600000.00 10
2500001.00 5600010.00 20
```

Script

```
import fileinput
import string
import os

# Declaration
env.overwriteOutput=True
env.workspace= outpath

x = []
y = []
z = []

newfc="newfc.shp" 
outpath="c:/tmp/"


# Create new Shapefile and add FIELDS
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outpath, newfc, "Point")
arcpy.AddField_management(newfc, "X", "FLOAT", field_length = 50)
arcpy.AddField_management(newfc, "Y", "FLOAT", field_length = 50)
arcpy.AddField_management(newfc, "Z", "FLOAT", field_length = 50)

# Reference Cursors
cursorX=arcpy.da.InsertCursor(newfc,"X")
cursorY=arcpy.da.InsertCursor(newfc,"Y")
cursorZ=arcpy.da.InsertCursor(newfc,"Z")

# Read File 
a = open("c:/tmp/test.txt","r")
inputF = a.readlines()

for line in inputF:
        xCoordinate, yCoordinate, zValue = line.split()
        x.append(float(xCoordinate))
        y.append(float(yCoodrinate))
        z.append(float(zValue))

print([x]) # [[2500000.0, 2500001.0]]
print([y]) # [[5600000.0, 5600010.0]]
print([z]) # [[10.0, 20.0]]

# Copy Arrays into the Field
cursorX.insertRow(x) # TypeError: value #0 - unsupported type: list
cursorY.insertRow((y)) # TypeError: sequence size must match size of the row
cursorZ.insertRow(z)
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you're trying to add data to the insert cursor one column at a time. Cursors think about the world one row at time. I recommend the following code. A few other notes... Python code runs in order, so make sure you declare your outpath variable before you set your env.workspace to outpath. Also, this code is going to create a shapefile with the attributes that you want, but it's not actually going to define a shape. (The fields you designated could have anything in them. The shapefile doesn't know that you're defining coordinates). So it will have an attribute table but no points will appear when you look at it in ArcMap. If that's what you're looking to do, check out [this article](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/python/writing-geometries.htm). There are code examples at the bottom for writing point geometries.

```
import arcpy

newfcName ="newfc.shp" 
outpath = r"c:/GIS"

# Declaration
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True
arcpy.env.workspace= outpath


# Create new Shapefile and add FIELDS
newfc = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outpath, newfcName, "Point")
arcpy.AddField_management(newfc, "X", "FLOAT", field_length = 50)
arcpy.AddField_management(newfc, "Y", "FLOAT", field_length = 50)
arcpy.AddField_management(newfc, "Z", "FLOAT", field_length = 50)

# Reference Cursors
cursor=arcpy.da.InsertCursor(newfc, ["X", "Y", "Z"])

# Read File 
a = open("c:/GIS/test.txt","r")
inputF = a.readlines()

for line in inputF:
    xCoordinate, yCoordinate, zValue = line.split(" ")
    newRow = (float(xCoordinate), float(yCoordinate), float(zValue))
    cursor.insertRow(newRow)

a.close()
```

If you want to write the geometry too, substitute this for the last few lines:

```
cursor=arcpy.da.InsertCursor(newfc, ["X", "Y", "Z", "SHAPE@XY"])

# Read File 
a = open("c:/GIS/test.txt","r")
inputF = a.readlines()

for line in inputF:
    mySplit = line.split(" ")
    xCoordinate = float(mySplit[0])
    yCoordinate = float(mySplit[1])
    zValue = float(mySplit[2])
    newRow = (xCoordinate, yCoordinate, zValue, (xCoordinate, yCoordinate))
    cursor.insertRow(newRow)

a.close()
```

Comment: you really helped me out, thanks for you extensive Explanation =)

Comment: nicely done. This can be applied to a csv as well correct?

Comment: No problem, Andriel. Welcome to python. It's a fun language! Ziggy, sure, it think it should work with a csv. But if your data is comma separated, be sure you change the split to accomodate that. So something like this: xCoordinate, yCoordinate, zValue = line.split(",")

Comment: Whoops. Just noticed there was an identation error in the code above under the "for line in inputF" section. I corrected it above.

Comment: if i wanted to add the xy geometries to a new feature class would I have to do that by adding those fields? i took a look at your geometry link but i am a bit confused on why the arcpy.Array is needed..

Comment: If you're reading from CSV in python, you'll find it much simpler in the long run if you use the builtin [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module. @ziggy, if you want to create/update point geometries themselves, you can use some form of the [`SHAPE@` tokens](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/insertcursor-class.htm).

Comment: Ziggy, I updated the code above with an option for how to write the geometry as well. You can skip the array and just add the XY as a tuple because it's just point data. (If you start getting into lines and polygon though, you need to make an array of points to make up the vertices of the more complicated shape. See?)

Comment: okay one last question, when creating the feature class i want to add the spatial reference without using a template fc. it keeps giving me an error because the spatial reference parameter in the tool is all the way at the end and I want to leave the template, m, z optional parameters blank. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yep, empty quotes will do. Like this: 'newfc = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outpath, newfcName, "Point", "", "", "", 26910)'